# SetWinEventHook with EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE behaves differently at random

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, hook

I am using SetWinEventHook in c# to hook into EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE events. and it worked great, except that on other PCs some actions seem not to fire the event as they do on my pc (within firefox for example)
I tried to recreate the issue and it happened a few times on my pc and then stopped but I got no idea why
When trying to find the problem I ran the app without debugging and the problem showed, but after tinkering a bit more it seemed that that was purely coincidental and the app is now running correctly even without debugging (and i can't seem to get it not to work again no matter what i do)
Any idea why that might happen?

Here I set up the hook:

```
_objectCreateHook = ObjectCreateHook;
_objectCreateHookId =  SetWinEventHook(0x8000, 0x8000, IntPtr.Zero, _objectCreateHook , 0, 0, 0) ;
```

And here is the callback function:

```
public void ObjectCreateHook(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject,
            int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
        {
            if (idObject == 0 || idObject == -4) return;
            Debug.WriteLine("HOLA? " + "-" + hwnd + "-" + idChild + "-" + dwEventThread + "-" + idObject);

        }
```

Comment: Are you making sure your hook procedure doesn't get garbage collected?

Comment: Yeah i am sure as it keeps working, it's just that some actions that that trigger the event on my PC don't on other PCs (and as mentioned a few successive times even not on my own PC for some reason)

Comment: Are you using a GCHandle for the callback function? From the docs: *'When you use SetWinEventHook to set a callback in managed code, you should use the GCHandle structure to avoid exceptions. This tells the garbage collector not to move the callback.'*

Comment: Oh i didn't know that. I implemented it and it worked on a different pc as intended, but then i undid my changes and it still worked . I am at a loss with this random behavior.

Comment: Well, maybe sometimes decides GC to move the object, sometimes not, depending on used/available memory, I'm not familiar with that. So I would use a GCHandle to make sure it doesn't get moved, as stated in the docs.

Comment: Well the problem is still there sometimes so that wasn't it sadly. But thanks anyway for the tip.

Comment: Are you using the WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT flag? Have you checked [Out-of-Context Hook Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/out-of-context-hook-functions)?

Comment: Yes, that is what the 0 in the last parameter is for.